# ValueError when splitting lines in a text file

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'd like to split each line of a text file into two by " - ", but I keep getting this error:

```
File "quiz.py", line 21, in Vocab
    questions, answers = line.split("-")
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I'm quite new to coding and could use some help. All tips are welcome as well!

```
import hashlib

testFile = ""
def qSearch():
    options = input ("Vocab/Grammar/or Special? (v/g/s)")
    if options == "v":
        testFile = "Vocabtest"
        Vocab()
    elif options == "g":
        Grammar()
        testFile = "Grammartest"
    elif options == "s":
        Special()
        testFile = "Specialtest"
    else:
        qSearch()

def Vocab():
        with open('Vocabtest.txt','r') as f:
            for line in f:
                questions, answers = line.split("-") ### error
                print (questions)

qSearch()
```

The text in my text file is formatted like so:

```
Magandang umaga - Good Morning

Magandang hapon - Good Afternoon

Magandang gabi - Good evening

Magandang umaga sa’yo - Good Morning to you

Magandang hapon din sa’yo - Good Afternoon to you to
```

Comment: You have a line in the file with more than one hyphen in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because on line 21 in your input text (.txt) file you have more than one `-` but you only expect one.

A safer way to do it would be to only split once:

```
questions, answers = line.split("-", 1)
```

Comment: but is it guaranteed that there's only one hypen in the question? it's just impossible to split properly in that case without more info.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri - Thank you for your clarification, I have cleared up the confusion

Comment: I did find an extra "-" within the text file, so I replaced "-" with "=" entirely. I have ran into another error however. I don't know what the standard is for asking questions within questions, but I've ran into this error now.

Comment: File "quiz.py", line 21, in Vocab
    questions, answers = line.split(" = ")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it doesn't matter if there are more than one, however  the should be a check to make sure there is at least one.

Comment: Nevermind! I missed one line that still had a "-" in it. I'll be more careful next time!

Comment: @Thrifts Yes, now your problem is there are no `-` to split on in that line since you changed it to `=`.  Did you try modifying the `split` in your code as I recommended with the original .txt input file?

Answer (score 1):

"Unpacking" is the name for what you're doing when you write

`value1, value2 = a_list`

When you do an assignment like that, you're implicitly making an assumption about how many values are contained in `a_list` -- here it's 2. If there's more or less than 2, there's no good way to give `value1` and `value2` values without doing very surprising and unhelpful things (like leaving one empty, or leaving some elements of the list unassigned).

So `too many values to unpack` means that there's at least one line in your file where `line.split('-')` results in more than 2 elements -- that is, there's at least one line with more than one `-`.

Comment: That clears up a lot actually thank you!